# PrepareForTest causes class.getPackage() to return null, workarounds?

Tags: java, mocking, powermock

I am trying to mock a private static final field, but the class has an method that invokes class.getPackage() which returns null when I am using @PrepareForTest.

```
package a.b.c.d;

public class Model {
    private static final String abc = createNewString();

    private static String createNewString() {
         return Model.class.getPackage().getName();
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ModelTest {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest()
    public void test() throws Exception {
        new Model();     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method getPackage returns the package of the class, or null if no package information is available from the archive or codebase.

To fix error define class *Model* inside package.

**EDIT:**

To mock static methods of class *Model* follow this instruction: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic

Comment: The class is defined in a package, I will update my description.

Comment: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ModelTest {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(Model.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Model.class)
    }
}

Didn't solve my issue because the createNewStringMethod is called before the test method. The call is trigerred by @PrepareForTest(Model.class)